# week to first day of week

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I have a week formatted like this: `2023-W12` (for Week 12 in 2023).

I need to get the first day of that week (in this case Monday, 2023-03-20 (yyyy-mm-dd)).

But I can only use plain cfml to achieve this, as of the systems limitation.

I tried `dateFormat('2023-W12', 'yyyy-mm-dd')` which leads to this error:

> The value of parameter 1, which is currently 2023-W12, must be a class java.util.Date value.

Any hints on how I could do this?

Comment: You might have to manually parse out the values using mid(), or a regex to get the parts (year, W??) numbers.  Then you can construct a date, see if it's Monday, if not, loop by -1 until you find a Monday.  There are math options as well....   I know you can output a week-based format, but not sure if you can parse a date with it....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `parseDateTime` function.

```
var date = parseDateTime( '2023-W12', "YYYY-'W'w");
// date is {ts '2023-03-19 00:00:00'}
```

Comment: IT seems you're looking for the first *Monday*, as opposed to the first day of the week (Sunday)?  If so, what @etchesketch suggested will work but it gives you the date of the Sunday of the week in question.   So, simply add a day like so:

<cfset adate = parseDateTime( '2023-W12', "YYYY-'W'w")>
<cfset firstMondayOfWeek = dateFormat(dateAdd('d',1,adate),"yyyy-mm-dd")>
<cfoutput>
    #adate#
    <br>
    #firstMondayOfWeek#
</cfoutput>

Comment: yeah in germany we have monday as first day of the week :-)
thx to both of you, that did work perfectly!